# what is the assembly language for a specific processor

Tags: processor

How to know your assembly language when you know your processor version?
Example: my processor version is Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "assembly language" is not influenced by the particular model of processor; in your case; you want an assembler for Intel x86-64.

There may be model-to-model variations on what instructions are supported; Intel provides data sheets that tell you that for each processor. Alternatively, you can glean the info from Wikipedia.

Finally, there may be a choice of assemblers. There is one from Intel and one from the GNU project.  The instruction syntax (i.e., the "assembly language") is very different between those two, for the same set of machine instructions.